# How to change multiple str to float in a file and then average the total without getting errors?

Tags: python, file

I am very new to coding so please elaborate and use examples to explain. I have a text file that has many numbers along with names and other str. I need to know how i can convert the numbers that are currently str into floats so i can calculate the average.

I have tried using the str as floats but i get error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
which is expected

i have also tried setting the str to float but it gives me

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leona\Desktop\School Work\moretesting.py", line 9, in 
    average = sum(num1) / len(num1)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

```
file = input("Enter a filename: ")

with open(file, "r") as f:

   next(f)

   for line in f:

       lines = line.split(",")

       num1 = float(lines[6])

       average = sum(num1) / len(num1)

       print(average)
```

The file has this inside (just a portion of the text file because its way to big but i just need to understand how to do this type of problem):

```
zip,eiaid,utility_name,state,service_type,ownership,comm_rate,ind_rate,res_rate
52346,9417,Interstate Power and Light Co,IA,Bundled,Investor Owned,0.0922343168969,0.0589686412318,0.130070934252
72424,814,Entergy Arkansas Inc,AR,Bundled,Investor Owned,0.0735129328027,0.0594501735324,0.0908957415387


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leona\Desktop\School Work\moretesting.py", line 9, in <module>
    average = sum(num1) / len(num1)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The `len` of a float doesn't make sense. You should add an inner for-loop over the items in `lines`, convert each, sum them up and finally divide by the `len` of `lines`.

Comment: `pandas` is great for this.

Comment: My guess is that you want to take in all the things after 7th element in `lines`. That would mean you need to take in `num1 = lines[6:]` and then convert all elements to floats like: `num1 = [float(i) for i in num1]`

Comment: @gmds, It is nice to suggest pandas. But, instead of teaching him how to cast magic, since he is new to programming I think is better to let him learn the hard way ;)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I only want to have the 6th element(comm_rate) be summed up and averaged. The text file is :                                                                            ['zip', 'eiaid', 'utility_name', 'state', 'service_type', 'ownership', 'comm_rate', 'ind_rate', 'res_rate']
['52346', '9417', 'Interstate Power and Light Co', 'IA', 'Bundled', 'Investor Owned', '0.0922343168969', '0.0589686412318', '0.130070934252']
['72424', '814', 'Entergy Arkansas Inc', 'AR', 'Bundled', 'Investor Owned', '0.0735129328027', '0.0594501735324', '0.0908957415387']

Comment: In the example provided, could you tell us what the expected output will be? It still confuses me since the 6th element is a single number and the average of a single number does not make sense. Do you want to take the average across all the lines? or take average of all the numbers in a single line?

Comment: the comm_rate section (6th element) is a huge list of numbers but i only listed 2 for the sake of space.

Comment: So for the above example, the average should be 0.0828736248...?

Comment: the text file has a comm_rate section (6th element) which is a huge list of numbers but i only listed 2 for the sake of space. It comes out as a str from the text file. The outcome should be the average of all the comm_rate numbers.

Comment: i dont know the average because it's very tedious to count hundreds/thousands of numbers from the text file. I didn't show all the numbers because they don't fit here

Answer (score 0):

You can append the values in that column to a list and then get the average of the list as follows:

```
file = input("Enter a filename: ")

with open(file, "r") as f:

  next(f)
  num_list = []

  for line in f:
    lines = line.split(",")
    num_list.append(float(lines[6])

  average = sum(l) / float(len(l))
  print(average)
```

Comment: Thank you and everyone else for their time! I got it to work! many thanks!!

Comment: Consider up-voting/accepting the answer if it helped.